# where can i find lollipop phone app source code?

Tags: android

I'm searching lollipop phone app source code in http://android.googlesource.com/

But, There is no tree for lollipop as the link shows
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Phone/+/lollipop-release

Other old version phone app source code exists in the web site.
android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Phone/+/eclair-sholes-release2

Is there other place to find the phone app source code?
or
Is there any reason the tree is empty?

Where should I start to find the source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is not too late. This seems to be what you need.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Dialer/

Comment: That's `com.android.dialer`, but the question is about `com.google.android.dialer` I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the latest source code for Phone app at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Phone/+/android-5.1.1_r1.

Comment: Thanks to reply. But, in the link, tree is empty. How can I get source code?